# LINQ Group Duplicate Rows and Delete All of Them Except The First one

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, duplicates

i have the following LINQ code which i found in a question on stackoverflow, i want to use it to delete the duplicate rows in the datatable and leave the one with the least index, here is the code and i can't figure out the code to be added in the commented line

```
    Dim duplicates = From row In GoogleResults.AsEnumerable()
           Let seller = row.Field(Of String)("Seller")
           Group row By seller Into DuplicateSellers = Group
           Where DuplicateSellers.Count() > 1
           Select DuplicateSellers
            For Each DuplicateSellerRows In duplicates
                For Each row In DuplicateSellerRows
                    'remove current row, but skip the first one
'row.Delete() will remove all rows but how can i keep the first one?
                Next
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to skip the first row in each group of duplicates:

```
For Each DuplicateSellerRows In duplicates
    For Each row In DuplicateSellerRows.Skip(1)            
        row.Delete() 
    Next
Next
```